# get index of item in listbox c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to get index of each items in a listbox 
Here is my code

```
           foreach (ListItem lstItem in lstCostCenter.Items)
           {
               int x = lstCostCenter.Items.IndexOf(lstItem);

           }
```

But each time its returning 0 only.

Please some one help me.

Thanks
Gulrej

Comment: Are all of your list items the same? Returing '0' as opposed to '-1' means that each ListItem is [Equal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ca35ayd.aspx) to the one in the zeroth index of the list. IndexOf returns the "zero-based index of the first occurrence" in the list. [IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4w08k17.aspx)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not use a for loop?

```
for (int i = 0; i < lstCostCenter.Items.Count; i++)
{
    ListItem lstItem = lstCostCenter.Items[i];
}
```

The index of the current item is `i`.